# Calling a .cmd file to execute Python script prints unnecessary errors

Tags: python, windows, selenium, cmd

I am running a file `start_selenium.cmd` with the simple command...

```
python selenium.py
```

If I was to run this in the actual command line, I would get all my expected `print` statements. But using the .cmd file to execute this script, I get errors and warnings mixed with my `print` statements. This includes pipe error and NOT IMPLEMENTED errors.

Anyway to suppress these errors without suppressing my print statements? This computer is actually running as a slave to do Selenium tests, so I wan't to keep the return as clean as possible. That is also why I am setting a .cmd file to trigger the Python script. Otherwise I have not used this type of execution before.

here are the NOT IMPLEMENTED errors...

```
[10828:8364:0318/174026:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(185)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10828:8364:0318/174026:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(760)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10828:8364:0318/174026:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(760)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

and pipe error...

```
[7784:10788:0318/174746:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(405)] pipe error: 232
```

I updated my chromedriver and selenium as a fix and still get the same errors.

Here is a very basic example of the python script (most removed):

```
...
from selenium import webdriver
import time
...
def dom_activity(driver, browsname):
start_time = time.clock()
max_tries = 5
attempted_tries = 1
while realpath not in driver.current_url and max_tries > 0:
    try:
        driver.get(realpath)
        driver.maximize_window()
        print 'PASS - ' + realpath + ' accessed using : ' +browsname
        tests['pass'] += 1
    except:
        max_tries -= 1
        attempted_tries += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    break
print 'attempts at homepage access = ' + str(attempted_tries) + '\n'
tests['exec'] += 1

driver.switch_to_active_element()

while realpath in driver.current_url:
    signinid = 'blah'
    max_tries = 5
    attempted_tries = 1
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id(signinid).click()
        print 'PASS - access to Sign In page using : ' +browsname
        tests['pass'] += 1
    except:
        if max_tries == 0:
            print 'FAIL - access to Sign In Page using : ' +browsname
            tests['fail'] += 1
            break
        max_tries -= 1
        attempted_tries += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    break
print 'attempts at signing in = ' + str(attempted_tries) + '\n'
tests['exec'] += 1

try:
    driver.find_element_by_id('blah2').send_keys(user['name'])
    driver.find_element_by_id('blah3').send_keys(user['pass'])
    driver.find_element_by_id('blah4').click()
except:
    print 'FAIL - processing Sign-In after keys and click, using : ' + browsname

cur_url = driver.current_url

if '/blah' in cur_url:
    print 'PASS - Signed in with : ' + browsname
    tests['pass'] += 1
else:
    print 'FAIL - Not Signed in with : ' + browsname + '\n the url after login is : ' + cur_url
    tests['fail'] += 1
tests['exec'] += 1
print browsname + ' took only ' + str(time.clock() - start_time) + ' seconds \n'
driver.close()
...
chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome()
dom_activity(chromedriver, 'Chrome')
...
print 'blah' + 'results'
```

Comment: Could you share the contents of `selenium.py` (or a reproducible example of it)?

Comment: Here you go @DavidRobinson I obviously had to remove some of it, so not exactly reproducible unless you add paths, users and have an actual sign in site. I can't unfortunately share this one. But a better idea at least.